# How to divide points into two sets - upper and lower part of profile

Tags: algorithm, language-agnostic, geometry, computational-geometry

I have lists of points in 3d (x,y,z)
For each list I want to divide that list into to two lists, one containing points from upper part of profile and second the lower half, just like that:

[image]

My question here is how to determine which point should go to upper-part and which one should go to lower part just from having those points with their coordinates (x,y,z).

Comment: Are there always an equal number of points in the "top" and "bottom"?

Comment: I'm afraid not, what if it would be?

Comment: I was thinking a quick and dirty way(if they were) would be to find the left most point, and label that and the next `n/2` points(going clockwise) as "top". However, it's really only for a specific circumstance, which you have confirmed is not the case.

Comment: If the points are always a closed curve, you could compute the curve outfacing normals and any points with a +y component in the normal would be the "upper part".

Comment: @MarkPing I like that idea, but wouldn't it also catch some on the upper-right side? For example, the bottom-most shape in the image would have some y+ normals on the right.

Comment: @MarkPing sounds interesting, but how could I calculate that?

Comment: I forgot you said it's in 3-space, I'm thinking in 2D.  But in 2D, for each successive pair of points, p & q, you get the vector between them as v = q-p.  Then the perpendicular vector is simply v2 = (v.y,-v.x).   You do need to make sure you're traversing the points in counter-clockwise order for this to work.  If this sounds reasonable I can expand it into a full answer.  What's the 3D part?  Do these shapes look like a circle bent in the middle like a Dali painting?  Or is each individual list in its own plane?

Comment: Oh, yes the "catching the wrong up" could be a problem.  Define "up" to be v=(-1,1) (pointing to the upper-left), and use that instead of v=(0,1)

Comment: On the picture all shapes have 1 clearly defined "top half", with the inside of the shape below it, and 1 "bottom half", with the inside of the shape above it. Is that always the case? Do you get something like a letter "C", which seems to have 2 tops and 2 bottoms, connected on C's left side? Or shapes with holes, like letter "R"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since points can be split in 'halves' in a lot of ways, it is good to have more criteria how to split them.

In this case it seems like you are looking for a curve, that splits point cloud, which has a shape similar to that cloud. Fitting curve of type that can cover your shapes can help. Probably polynomial of second or third order are good for these shapes.

Second idea is to create something that goes through 'middle of geometry'. In 2D case you could use medial axis approach. It can be computed for point cloud by Delaunay triangulation. If points are near some plane, you can project them on the plane and use this approach.

Answer (score 1):

First, create "lines" between each adjacent point. Assuming the points are given in order around the loop, this should be easy.

Then, cast a line from `0,0`(upper left) to each point. If it intersects another line to get there, it's not on the upper side. If it doesn't, it is.

It's O(n^2), so I'm **sure** there is a better solution, but for small sets of points, it should be fine. Note that it won't work on extremely concave shapes, but will for all of those shown.

Comment: Ok, I get it know. I will try to implement this know.

Comment: Optimizing this would be to use a sweep-line algorithm, where the sweep line is in the "up" direction (toward 0,0?).  That brings it down to O(n log n).

Answer (score 1):

Join adjacent edges to get lines.. Taking anticlockwise angles as positive..
In the upper part of the cloud, successive lines have increasing angles..
while in the lower part the successive lines have decreasing angles..

A lil trial and error should lead you to an appropriate hueristic..

[image]